SenseHat “zero” orientation
For some preface I wanted to do a little project with a Pi Zero 2W + sensehat/small display to have a gauge for lean angle on my motorcycle
I found this senseHat (B) https://www.waveshare.com/sense-hat-b.htm which looks like it’ll fit nicely with the Pi Zero. Maybe this question is not specific to this senseHat model but gyroscopes in general?
I wanted to know:
How does the senseHat/gyroscope know what a “0” lean angle looks like? Do they normally zero out to assume whatever position the sensor starts in is “0” lean angle or does the sensor have some sort of absolute zero that no matter which way it starts the angle is relative to which way gravity pulls down?
It would be hard I think to zero out the sensor if there is no absolute zero since the bike on the kickstand is leaning and I’m just guessing if I try to level out the bike and start the pi up after I think it’s leveled.
Any input would be much appreciated I have no idea how this would work in the real world and would love some idea of how it works before I buy everything
Thank you very much!

Hi Ryan, welcome to RPi SE. Your question strikes me as much more about how gyroscopes work than Raspberry Pi. As such, it's considered "off-topic" here. To get an answer to your question, you might try a search, or Wikipedia. OTOH, If I've mis-interpreted your question, please feel free to edit your question to bring it into accordance with RPi SE guidelines

you can only measure the angle when the bike is stationary

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is off-topic but simply answerable.
These devices contain a 3 axis accelerometer and if mounted "horizontally" one axis responds to the acceleration due to gravity. There is extensive documentation on 3 axis accelerometers if you care to search.
The other axes allow rotational velocity to be determined.
